# Use ls to list backup files only

Tags: ls, wildcards

I have a large number of "backup" files of the form `'#e.xvg.i#'`, where `i` ranges from 1 to 60. A file `e.xvg` also exists in the same directory. For example:

```
e.xvg
'#e.xvg.1#'
'#e.xvg.2#'
...
```

On bash, how do I use `ls` to list ONLY the backup files?

`ls '#e*#'` returns "No such file or directory", while `ls #e*#` appears to list ALL files in the directory.

Comment: `ls "#e*#"` maybe? (double quotes)

Answer (score 4):

Since an unquoted `#` introduces a comment, you will have to quote or  escape it:

```bsh
ls -ld \#e*\#
```

or

```bsh
ls -ld '#'e*'#'
```

You may also turn off interactive comments (in the `bash` shell) using

```bsh
shopt -u interactive_comments
```

This stops unquoted `#` being interpreted as a comment character in an interactive shell session.

Comment: unquoted `#` at the start of a word, so `ls -l \#e*#` should also work

Answer (score 2):

Take the star out of the quoted string so that the shell can see it, but make sure the `#` is quoted so it's not seen as a start-of-comment character.

```
ls '#'e*'#'
```